# Twitter Bootstrap Carousel: Display a clicked image in Modal Popup

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to display an image from my Twitter Bootstrap Carousel in a popup modal so I can allow the viewer to print an image they like. Right now, when I click on any carousel image, the modal always shows only the last image in my array rather than the image actually I clicked on.

My carousel code inside my carousel-inner class is:

```
<?php
foreach($photos as $photos):
  $image_now = $photos->image_path();
  <div class="item">
      <a href="#launch" data-toggle="modal">
        <img src="../<?php echo $image_now; ?>"  />
      </a>
  </div>
  <?php 
endforeach; 
?>
```

And my #launch modal code is:

```
<section id="launch" class="modal hide fade">
  <div id="printThis">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <img src="../<?php echo $image_now; ?>"  />
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Following Skelly's advice, I have now set up a second loop with unique launch id's. This results in the the first photo not getting displayed in the modal but the second one will. (Note: the $photo loop above uses the $i counter and this loop for the modal uses $j counter):

```
$j = 0;
foreach($photos as $photos): 
  $j++;
  $launch = "launch" . $j;  
  if ( $i == $j ) {  ?>
    <section id=<?php echo $launch; ?> class="modal hide fade">

    <div id="printThis">
      <div class="modal-body">
            <img src="../<?php echo $image_now; ?>"  />
      </div>
    </div>

  </section>
  <?php 
  } 
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looping through $photos to create each modal?

Each section should have a unique id (ie:launch1,launch2,etc..) that is referenced by the `href="#launch.."` in your .item DIVs

### **Here's a demo:** http://bootply.com/61231

Comment: Thanks Skelly, I followed your suggestion and set up a loop so that I have a unique launch id's. I have only 2 photos, and the popup modal only appears for the 2nd photo (when the 1st photo is clicked, nothing happens and no error msg).

Comment: Can you post the HTML that is rendered?

Comment: Thanks Skelly, I looked at your demo and followed your suggestion and then I set up a 2nd $photo loop that creates Sections with unique launch id's. Now, the popup modal only appears for the 2nd photo (when the 1st photo is clicked, nothing happens and no error msg). Have been hacking and testing and just not sure why this is happening. Thanks for any further input.

Comment: Skelly: This is my first time to use Stack Overflow. Do I click on "Answer Your Question" button to post my code?

Comment: No , you Edit your existing question

Comment: Skelly, thanks for your solution! I applied it and finally worked out my own bugs a moment ago after I fully realized how it works. Case solved and I appreciate greatly your help!

Comment: I have been unable to get the Print button on the modal to work...any ideas?